# How do I create a table for a SQL Union in Teradata?

Tags: mysql, union, teradata

I want to merge two tables together to develop a master listed of patient IDs.

1. My question is where is this data being stored?
2. I want to do a left join with the results of the union. Is there a way to move these results to a table?

   ```
   SELECT patid FROM sandbox_jp.claims_women_dx_preg2
   UNION
   SELECT patid FROM sandbox_jp.claims_women_px_preg2;
   ```

Comment: Which database do you use? The tag "sql" does not tell us enough as each dbms vendor has slight variations in syntax.

Comment: You could put this in an inner query and use it as a (virtual) table, if all you need is a JOIN with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl 
SELECT patid FROM db1.claims_women_dx_preg2 
UNION 
SELECT patid FROM sandbox_jp.claims_women_px_preg2
;
```

but the syntax is different for other databases e.g. SQL Server:

```
CREATE patid
into new_tbl 
from (
    SELECT patid FROM [dbo].claims_women_dx_preg2 
    UNION 
    SELECT patid FROM [sandbox_jp].claims_women_px_preg2
    ) u
;
```

Note I assume the 2 tables you are unioning are different somehow, no point using the same table in that union query.

If it is only needed for a limited time, and your database supports "with" then

```
with cte as (
        SELECT patid FROM [dbo].claims_women_dx_preg2 
        UNION 
        SELECT patid FROM [sandbox_jp].claims_women_px_preg2
)
select
*
from cte
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. To clarify I am using Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

The CTE logic in @User_By_Already's answer will also work for Teradata.

You can also put the results into a volatile table:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT as (
SELECT patid FROM sandbox_jp.claims_women_dx_preg2
UNION
SELECT patid FROM sandbox_jp.claims_women_px_preg2)
with data
primary index(patid)
on commit preserve rows;
```

You can then select from that volatile table, joining to your other table.

Or, you can use a derived table, again joining to your other table.

```
select
...
from
(SELECT patid FROM sandbox_jp.claims_women_dx_preg2
UNION
SELECT patid FROM sandbox_jp.claims_women_px_preg2) p
join <other table> on ...
```